# how to generate crypted password for auto install

Tags: system-installation, preseed, cloud-init

The instructions for [auto install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) of ubuntu 20.4 talks about an encrypted password  $crypted_pass.

```
version: 1
identity:
    hostname: hostname
    username: username
    password: $crypted_pass
```

how do I generate this for any given password? I've tried a straight sha-512 hash but this doesn't work

From [these](https://medium.com/@tlhakhan/ubuntu-server-20-04-autoinstall-2e5f772b655a) instructions it appears I should get

```
$6$FhcddHFVZ7ABA4Gi$9l4yURWASWe8xEa1jzI0bacVLvhe3Yn4/G3AnU11K3X0yu/mICVRxfo6tZTB2noKljlIRzjkVZPocdf63MtzC0
```

for `root` but the sha-512 hash of `root` is

```
99ADC231B045331E514A516B4B7680F588E3823213ABE901738BC3AD67B2F6FCB3C64EFB93D18002588D3CCC1A49EFBAE1CE20CB43DF36B38651F11FA75678E8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crypted string that you get will depend on the *salt* value - to reproduce the one in the example you would need to duplicate its 16-character salt:

```
$ printf 'root' | openssl passwd -6 -salt 'FhcddHFVZ7ABA4Gi' -stdin
$6$FhcddHFVZ7ABA4Gi$9l4yURWASWe8xEa1jzI0bacVLvhe3Yn4/G3AnU11K3X0yu/mICVRxfo6tZTB2noKljlIRzjkVZPocdf63MtzC0
```

See also:

- [Why is the output of “openssl passwd” different each time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510990/why-is-the-output-of-openssl-passwd-different-each-time)

Comment: Thank you so much - now I have a further problem...  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261461/linux-auto-install-salt-not-being-stored-in-etc-shadow